# Disable /Deny "Loopback" "Internal dummy connection"requests Apache 2.4

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, apache2.4

We have implemented Apache 2.4 with IPV6 disable. I am getting **"Internal Dummy connections"** log entries inside access log.

The following is the snapshot of my error:

[image: Following is the snapshot of my error]

I tried searching for the solutions on Internet, everywhere it is mentioned that  exclude these log entries from the access log. Reference:

https://knackforge.com/blog/sivaji/mitigating-apache-internal-dummy-connection-issue

I want solution for disabling or denying this kind of request on the server.

Comment: From an apparently more primary source, [*"These requests are perfectly normal and you do not, in general, need to worry about them. They can simply be ignored."*](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/InternalDummyConnection)  Why are you trying to disable something that appears to be a normal part of how it is designed to work?

Comment: They are consuming the memory of the server & also increases the cpu  load

Comment: Neither of those assertions should be correct.  See https://serverfault.com/q/333267/153161 and https://serverfault.com/q/480044/153161.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.